# How to display a popup in the same window and close this immediately?

Tags: c#

I have a big problem:

I am loading with a `webBrowser` a website. On this website my program is searching for a button and clicking it:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "single_like_button")
    {
       element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

But it is opening a new window as an IE popup.  I want to display this window inside a form (for background work), and close this popup immediately after opening (because when you close the popup, the script on the site continues running).

Any ideas?

Comment: Which window are you wanting to display inside the form?  The parent window or the popup?

Comment: I want display inside the form only popup

Comment: So, anyone has got an idea?

Comment: I am guessing that you aren't getting any traction on this issue because it is too unclear and/or you need to post all the relevant code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HzQMbWuZ

Comment: Maybe something with newWindow

Answer (score 0):

NewWindow event just lets you cancel it.  Your best bet is to parse the needed elements and find out what URL it will attempt to navigate to and then use that URL however you want.

This is under the assumption that the program is doing the clicking and not a user.

What is the program being used for?

Comment: Button is generated by javascript. Simple code: OuterHtml = "<A class=single_like_button onclick=openFbLWin_xxxxxx();>Subscribe</A>" i can extract onclick value, but what next?